# Task to download an image from URL

Tags: python, parsing, url, download

So, my main.py file for downloading an image from url is pretty simple:

```
def dowload_screenshot():
    task_id = 'task_id_which_is_used_to_find_needed_server'
    data_url = extract_render_host(task_id) #here i have a function which builds correct url, because it alwas had different endings, depending on which host is running render.
    

    response = session.get(data_url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'), stream=True)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        time.sleep(5)
        print('Sleeping for 5 seconds') #thats written because first seconds after connecting to url - its showing loading screen.
    
        image_data = BytesIO(response.content)
        return Image.open(image_data)
    else:
        print('Failed to fetch image')
        return None
```

The problem is that web-page is built weird. It has only one image on a whole web-page, and thats a screenshot of desktop where the render happens. Program on C+ is constantly deleting and uploading screenshots on that URL which makes impossible for me to download it. It simply got deleted before image download starts.
Also, i have tried to 'stream=True' which is not working, because there is no problem of too big data to download, it simply constantly deleted and uploaded, and image has the exact same name always. Which means that download may continue forever.

it's also important to mention that i dont want to use tools like `selenium`, because i don't need browser to be open on machine.

So i have a question: how may i achieve my goal and download an image for future parsing and formatting?